# executar um codigo a cada 5 segundos em vb.net

Tags: vb.net

eu tenho um codigo que verifica se a aplicação esta correndo, caso ela não esteja, o codigo inicia  aplicação, caso esteja e ele passa... Mas ele faz isso apenas qnd eu executo pela 1° vez. Eu qria q ele verificava a cada 5 segundos..
***em vb.net**

codigo:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim activo As Boolean
    Dim myprocesses As Process()
    myprocesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("check") 
    If myprocesses.Length > 0 Then  
        activo = True 
    Else
        activo = False 
        Dim p As New ProcessStartInfo("check.exe")
        p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        p.CreateNoWindow = True
        Process.Start(p)

    End If

    System.Console.ReadKey()

End Sub
```

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor o que esta acontecendo? Mostrar o que você está tentando? Isto é, mostre o seu código para ajudar as pessoas a entender o que você quer.

Comment: editei, tipo assim, eu qro que a cada 5 segundo o codigo q eu editei la em cima rode. 1-INICIEI A APLICAÇÃO, 2-VERIFICOU, 3-PASSOU 5 SEGUNDO, 4-VERIFICOU... e assim por diante

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a classe `Timer`:

```
'Declare um variável do tipo Timer: 
Private tempo As New System.Timers.Timer(5000) '5000 = 5 segundos

'Adicione um handler para capturar o evento tick do timer: 
AddHandler tempo.Elapsed, AddressOf DispararTimer

'Adicione a sub que representa o evento tick do timer:
Public Sub DispararTimer(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
  'Código que você quer que execute de 5 em 5 segundos
End Sub

'Por último, no load do formulário, habilite o timer:
tempo.Enabled = True
```

---

Resposta baseada [nesse post do Macoratti](http://www.macoratti.net/vbn_time.htm).